# binary communication with XMLHttpRequest in Safari and iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari

In chrome it is reported that by using a code like the following, it is possible to do binary communication with a server (instead of the traditional base64 communication).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = ...
var data = new ArrayBuffer(byteArray.length);
var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data);        
for (i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++) {
    ui8a[i] = byteArray[i] & 0xff;
}
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append(data);
xhr.send(bb.getBlob());
```

Assuming Chrome and Safari embracing HTML5 in a similar fashion, is there a way to do this in Safari and iOS Safari?

Answer (score 1):

**new BlobBuilder()** does not work on Mobile Safari, you can use **new Blob()** like this:

```
xhr.send( new Blob([data], { 'type' : ... }) );
```

Comment: new Blob is not working for me in safari can u help me by providing the links or can u share your code

Comment: you can check http://gokercebeci.com/dev/canvasresize and http://gokercebeci.com/dev/droparea and if you still have a problem, tell me